# How to create email reply / method to code a reply?

Tags: php, email

I'm building an app which responds to emails on behalf of my app users. These emails are sent to my users and intercepted by my app to auto-respond to their clients. The emails come from third parties and contain branded formatting.

My PHP app takes the full HTML of the email, stores it in a MySQL table then creates a reply and appends the HTML under a `<hr/>` at the bottom of the email.

This works and it looks like a reply (which is my intention (although I will build some header detail to make it look more legitimate as if it was replied to in Outlook or similar)).

My problem, however, is that this method hurts the reply formatting - it seems to take on styles like line-height from the original email HTML at the bottom of the reply.

Thus my question is, how do I create a reply email? Do do what I'm doing and style my reply better, or do I need to do more with the complete original, not just the HTML output. And is it even ok to have to HTML tags in an email?

I would love it if the answer was something like: extract the X from the email and build a reply with the opensource Y library :)

**EDIT: Email examples as requested**

This third party email contains a head that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
body{font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;}
a{color: #06c;}
p{margin:0;}
#message{width:600px;margin:0 auto;}
.legal{margin-top:2em;}
.footer{margin-top:1em;padding:5px;background:#999999;color:#fff;}
.footer a{color:#fff;}
.senderName,.label{font-weight:bold;}
.link,.label,.hint{margin-top: 20px;}
.header-separator{height:4px;background-color:#e4002b;width:100%;margin-top:17px;}
tr,td{vertical-align:top;text-align:left;}
img{border:0;}
${css!""}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='message'>
...
```

And my user email templates (built in TinyMCE) will look something like this:

```
<p><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; line-height: 14pt;">Dear [name],</span></p>
<p><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; line-height: 14pt;">Thanks for your enquiry
...
```

When I send the email to the email service it's as simple:

```
$emailreply = $userTemplate . '<hr/>' . $originalEnquiry;
```

Surely, that's not good enough? Also, this is the email that I mentioned where line-height is being affected - so my user templates are not sending as designed.

Comment: Could you post the markup of one of the emails? This would help to understand your problem.

Comment: Do you want to keep the original email styling or modify it?

Comment: I want it to look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda *rare* the case on the 3rd party email, having separated `<style >` tag when the usual procedure on HTML email development is to set up all styles inline.

It's kinda *logical* that those styles (from the `<style >` tag are damaging your new code, The best option here is to make all that styling (from the 3rd party email) inline, so you can remove the `<style >` tag, keeping both email styling separated.

As you said **PHP App**, I think you can use some of the following:

- https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles
- https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier
- https://github.com/emilsundberg/Laravel-HTML-email-inliner/blob/master/src/Emil/Inliner/vendor/Premailer/Premailer.php

And make sure, if the chosen one of the above tools doesn't remove the `<style>...</style>` tag, remove it by yourself (you can do it using regular expressions).

Hope this helps, good luck